# CActiveDataProvider complex condition

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have a table wall_messages with the following columns

id
from_user_id
subject
message
date
message_reply_id

I want to obtain a CActiveDataProvider with all the wall messages that have a given value for the _from_user_id_ column. So far so good.

```
        $outgoingMessages = new CActiveDataProvider ('Messages', array ( 
        'criteria' => array (
            'condition' => 'from_user_id ='.$userId->id,
        ), 
        'pagination' => array ( 
            'PageSize' => 5, 
        ) 
    ));
```

Now, I need to add the following condition: for those wall messages with matching _from_user_id_ value AND matching _message_reply_id_ value, I only want to keep one of those rows. Which one? The one with the "oldest" date. How can I do this? Im not good at all with sql queries so this is kind of hard for me. thanks!

I came up with a temporary solution which is the extreme opposite of elegant:

```
    $sentMessages = array();
    $alreadyIncludedMessages = array();

    foreach ($user->messagesOut as $mess) {
        if (!in_array($mess->message_reply_id, $alreadyIncludedMessages)){
            $sentMessages[] = $mess;
            $alreadyIncludedMessages[]=$mess->message_reply_id;
        } 
    }
    $outgoingMessages = new CActiveDataProvider ('Messages', array ( 
        'pagination' => array ( 
            'PageSize' => 5, 
        ),
        'data'=>$sentMessages
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to just return one value, you can use something like:

```
  'criteria' => array (
    'condition' => 'from_user_id = :userId AND message_reply_id = :messageId',
    'order' => 'date ASC',
    'params' => array(':userId'=>$userId->id, ':messageId'=>$messageId)
  ),
  'pagination' => array ( 
    'PageSize' => 1,
  )
```

and don't display the pagination.
If you are looking to display the oldest message for each user, you will probably have to use a subquery or populate an array and then use *CArrayDataProvider* which can be useful for complex queries.

Comment: unfortunately i need to display more than one value. i'm starting to look into the CArrayDataProvider suggestion because i'm used to working with CActiveDataProvider.. not that familiar with CArrayDataProvider!

Comment: in case i can pull this off with CArrayDataProvider, is it possible to use the resulting data for a CListView? Because till now i have always used data of type CActiveDataProvider, and i ask this because i use this resulting data set in a CListView

Comment: Yes, you can use it for CListView.